# Slow performance with injected library OS X DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES

Tags: macos, dll, shared-libraries, code-injection

I wrote a small library that overrides the system library function `gettimeofday()` with a slightly different one that returns the time minus a hardcoded offset.

I inject that with `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` into the application (an old 3D tool that crashes on dates > 2014). However with the library injected the performance is roughly half compared to without it.

I don't really know a lot about how OSX and dynamic libraries work, I just got that working after reading a lot of tutorials and trial and error.

I can't believe the performance drop is caused by just adding that tiny code change but I read it might have something to do with namespace flattening, which I don't understand.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of the performance overhead?

```
#include <sys/time.h>

//compile:
//clang -c interpose.c
//clang -dynamiclib -o interpose.dylib -install_name interpose.dylib interpose.o

#define DYLD_INTERPOSE(_replacment,_replacee) \
  __attribute__((used)) static struct{ const void* replacment; const void* replacee; } _interpose_##_replacee \
  __attribute__ ((section ("__DATA,__interpose"))) = { (const void*)(unsigned long)&_replacment, (const void*)(unsigned long)    &_replacee };

int mygettimeofday(struct timeval *restrict tp, void *restrict tzp);

DYLD_INTERPOSE(mygettimeofday, gettimeofday)

int mygettimeofday(struct timeval *restrict tp, void *restrict tzp)
{
    int ret = gettimeofday(tp, tzp);
    tp->tv_sec -= 123123;
    return ret;
}
```

Edit:

I also wrote a tiny test tool that does nothing but call `gettimeofday()` 100000000 times, and ran it with and without the lib. Without it consistently takes `2.9 seconds`, with library injected it takes `3.0 seconds`, so the extra code in `mygettimeofday` should not be the issue.

Comment: Using `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` can affect the dyld cache, so it's possible that's why you notice the performance hit.